# Operator overloading on temporary

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I'm having some problem trying to use bitshift operator on a temporary object returned by a method.

The idea is to create a Log object as a temporary, and through the bitshift operator, append values which would be stored in a std::stringstream object.

On the destruction of the temporary, the std::stringstream would dump its contents, however, the destructor gets called before I can append the first string.

A small example:

```
class LogEntry
{
public:
    LogEntry(int level) : m_level{level}
    {
    }

    ~LogEntry()
    {
        // dump m_out on destruction
        Widget(m_out.str());
    }

    template <typename T>
    LogEntry& operator<<(T& arg)
    {
        m_out << arg;

        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::stringstream m_out;
    const int m_level;
}
```

And this is how I intend to use it:

```
LogEntry(LOG_LEVEL_DEFAULT) << "This is a string" << 1234;
```

So far, the destructor is being called before the bitshift operator, meaning that the memory is already corrupted when appending the contents to m_out.

Does anyone know how to ensure that the operator will be called before the temporary's destruction?

Comment: `LogEntry entry(LOG_LEVEL_DEFAULT) << "This is a string" << 1234;` is a syntax error and it's not clear what you meant to type.

Comment: Doesn't compile: `error: expected ',' or ';' before '<<' token` on your intended use line.

Comment: Well, I edited the code. I guess I made a mistake transcribing as I'm not in a PC with my IDE. I hope now you can address the question.

Comment: That code, as mentioned in Donghui Zhang's answer, won't call `LogEntry`'s destructor until after the operator functions have been called. When you get back to your PC, can you check what you actually have that doesn't work?

Comment: I'm with @hvd. I'd go one step further by suggesting you NOT post a question UNLESS you are in front of a PC to ensure your question is valid. In this case, the lvalue reference vs. universal reference problem I pointed out will prevent your code from compiling; and you made a false claim that the destructor is called before the operators. There are many many people monitoring stackoverflow.com trying to help, and you shouldn't waste people time.

Comment: Sorry I wasted your most valuable time. Way to go promoting a good atmosphere in the community. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @hvd and @Richard Critten in the comment, your code does not compile. If you want a temporary variable that only lives in the statement, you could do so without giving it a name, such as:

```
LogEntry(LOG_LEVEL_DEFAULT) << "This is a string" << 1234;
```

And if you do so, the two operators will be called BEFORE the destructor is called.

But there is another problem. Your operator<<(T& arg) takes as input an lvalue reference, while 1234 is NOT an lvalue. To fix this second problem, you could change the operator to take as argument a universal reference: operator<<(T&& arg).

Comment: This doesn't try to answer the question, so shouldn't have been posted as an answer. You don't cover the temporary's destruction (the whole point of the question) at all. It could be useful as a comment though, I think.

Comment: @hvd  the code I gave does call the operators before the destructor. I've updated the answer to include that statement.

Comment: You're right, and now that you mentioned it, it should've been a valid answer to the question. The OP has edited the question claiming that exactly this doesn't work though.